# How to send an e-mail if a particular word is present in subject using Python

Tags: python, email, outlook, pywin32

I have sent an automated e-mail using python with the following subject: **"Daily Test Results are completed and please find the Test Results"**. Once this is done, I should wait and search for the reply for this email with the following subject: **"Daily Test Results are completed and please find the Test Results - CHECK OK/VERIFIED/SEND/PASS_SEND"**
Once I receive the mail with the new subject, then through python I must share the original mail with the first subject to multiple users.

I am not sure on two points:

1. For subject ending with CHECK OK/VERIFIED/SEND/PASS_SEND, I am not able to give a list and instead give only one keyword
2. If I give one keyword and search, I am able to get the mail, but I am not sure how to share the original mail to remaining participants

Can some one please help me with this

**Code:**

```
import win32com.client as win32
from datetime import date
def mail_check():
    Outlook = win32.Dispatch('Outlook.Application').GetNameSpace('MAPI')
    inbox = Outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
    sub = [message for message in inbox.Items if 'CHECK OK' in message.Subject]
    for mssg in sub:
        print(mssg)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    mail_check()
```

Comment: what happens if you search for the first full subject line? do you see the first email of all the emails

Comment: @0m3r: Now I am able to search for a particular key word is present or not and pull the respective mail. But if I have a list of keywords and from that if any one word is present in the subject, then it should give me that mail